# Having trouble finding the sum of an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have trouble evaluating:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\sin\left(\frac{4}{n}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{4}{n+1}\right)\right]$$
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a telescopic sum.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Write down the first 2 terms, then the first 3, ... notice there are cancellations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write out the first terms:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin\frac{4}{n}-\sin\frac{4}{n+1}\right)=\sin\frac{4}{1}-\sin\frac{4}{2}+\sin\frac{4}{2}-\sin\frac{4}{3}+\sin\frac{4}{3}-\sin\frac{4}{4}+\cdots
\end{equation}
Now all the terms except for the first one will cancel. Since the terms get smaller and smaller the sum will converge (this can be made more formally if you want, but I feel like we are only after determining the value, assuming that the sum converges). So the answer is $\sin(4)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that

$$\require{cancel}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(\sin \frac{4}{n} - \sin \frac{4}{n+1}\Big)=\sin \frac{4}{1} - \cancel{\sin \frac{4}{2}} + \cancel{\sin \frac{4}{2}} - \cancel{\sin \frac{4}{3}} + \cdots $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you I kept trying to solve it right away not realizing I could cancel out terms

Comment: You're welcome!!